# document.getElementById returns null when others work fine

Tags: javascript, exception, isnull

I have seen numerous other posts here at SO and across the web, but those deal with trying to add the event handler before the element is created.  My situation is different.

I have an html document that has the following segment:

```
<nav id="main_menu">                
            <ul>                
                <li id="liMapFilter" class="list"><img id="imgFilter" src="images/filter_icon.png">Filter</li>
                <li id="liDiagnostics" class="list"><img id="imgTools" src="images/tools_icon.png">Administration</li>              
            </ul>           
        </nav>
```

I set after page is loaded, a number of event handlers by calling:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    home.init();
});
```

within the `home.init()` function I set the following listener:

```
var elmMapFilter = document.getElementById('liMapFilter"');
cs_core.addEvent(elmMapFilter, 'click', home.showDialogMapFilter, false);
```

All the other listener handlers wire up just fine, but this particular one always throws a null reference.  I cannot understand when this handler works just fine:

```
var elmDiagnostics = document.getElementById('liDiagnostics');
cs_core.addEvent(elmDiagnostics, 'click', core.showDiagnostics, false);
```

Please advise.

Comment: So you're using jQuery, you're just not using it for everything.

Comment: where is your script being executed ? share your HTML please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got a typographic error. There's a stray `"` character in your id.

Comment: That's it.  THANK YOU - it was driving me crazy!!!

Comment: +1 - Seriously good eye sight !

Comment: Nice catch. sometimes, there is a need to do the null check and undefined check in the javascript for uninterrupted flow of execution